# Computing a column based on comparisons of other columns in table

Tags: sql-server, database, calculated-columns

Ok I am working on a database table with 4 columns, lets say a *first name, middle name, last name and a group id*. I want to group people based on the fact that they have the same `first` and `last names` regardless of their `middle name`. I also want to, if a new entry comes in, give that entry the correct group id. 
Here is an example of the result:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|  First_Name |  Middle_Name  |  Last_Name  |  Group_ID  |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  Jon        |  Jacob        |  Schmidt    |   1        |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  William    |  B.           |  Schmidt    |   1        |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  Sally      |  Anne         |  Johnson    |   2        |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm not sure whether or not this falls under the jurisdiction of a *computed column*, some kind of join or something far less obscure, Please help!

Comment: Your example appears to be showing that `'Jon' = 'William'`.

Comment: And if you added "Jon Johnson" to the data, what would the new groups be?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to enumerate the groups within a query then `row_number()` will work for you:

```
declare @Names table ( First_Name varchar(10), Middle_Name varchar(10), Last_Name varchar(10))
insert into @Names
    select 'Jon', 'Jacob', 'Schmidt' union all
    select 'William', 'B.', 'Schmidt' union all
    select 'Sally', 'Anne', 'Johnson' union all
    select 'Jon', 'Two', 'Schmidt'

;with Groups (First_Name, Last_Name, Group_ID) as
(   select  First_Name, Last_Name, row_number()over(order by Last_Name)
    from    @Names
    group
    by      First_Name, Last_Name
)
select  n.First_Name, n.Middle_Name, n.Last_Name, g.Group_Id
from    @Names n
join    Groups g on
        n.First_Name = g.First_Name and
        n.Last_Name = g.Last_Name;
```

Be aware the Group_ID value will change as new nameGroups are introduced.

If you want to assign and **persist** a Group_ID then I would suggest creating an ancillary table and assign the Group_IDs there.

By storing the mapping outside of the @Names table you are allowing users to change their names and not have to worry about re-evaluating the group assignment. It also allows you to modify the grouping logic without re-assigning names. You also have the ability to map *similar* enough values to the same grouping (John, Jon, Jonny).

Group_ID is composed of a First_Name and Last_Name. So, store it that way.

```
declare @Names table ( First_Name varchar(10), Middle_Name varchar(10), Last_Name varchar(10))
insert into @Names
    select 'Jon', 'Jacob', 'Schmidt' union all
    select 'William', 'B.', 'Schmidt' union all
    select 'Sally', 'Anne', 'Johnson' union all
    select 'Jon', 'Two', 'Schmidt'

declare @NameGroup table (Group_Id int identity(1,1), First_Name varchar(10), Last_Name varchar(10) unique(First_Name, Last_Name));
insert into @NameGroup (First_Name, Last_Name)
    select 'Jon', 'Schmidt' union all
    select 'Sally', 'Johnson';


declare @Group_ID int;

declare @First_Name varchar(10), 
        @Middle_Name varchar(10),
        @Last_Name varchar(10)

select  @First_Name = 'Jon',
        @Middle_Name = 'X',
        @Last_Name = 'Schmidt'

--be sure the Id has already been assigned
insert into @NameGroup
    select @First_Name, @Last_Name
    where  not exists(select 1 from @NameGroup where First_Name = @First_Name and Last_Name = @Last_Name)

--resolve the id
select  @Group_ID = Group_ID 
from    @NameGroup 
where   First_Name = @First_Name and 
        Last_Name = @Last_Name;

--store the name
insert into @Names (First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name)
    values(@First_Name, @Middle_Name, @Last_Name);


select  n.First_Name, n.Middle_Name, n.Last_Name, ng.Group_Id
from    @Names n
join    @NameGroup ng on
        n.First_Name = ng.First_Name and
        n.Last_Name = ng.Last_Name;
```